# how to give conditional comments in firefox for a single css style statement

Tags: css

I have a class with the following attributes

```
.vote{
    position:absolute;
        margin: 53px 3px 0 60px;
     }
```

But i want to give the margin: 53px 3px 0px 60px in firefox and

margin:53px 3px 0 115px in chrome. What i have to do for that using conditional comments

Comment: Conditional comments are an IE thing.

Comment: you could use javascript (and/or jQuery) to sniff the browser and apply the corresponding style

Comment: Here's a comprehensive list of browser hacks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript for detecting](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2008/09/22/javascript-get-browser/) the users browser via [userAgent](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml), than according to the result you can aply the needed style.

```
function getBrowser()
{
  var browser = navigator.userAgent;
  if (browser.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1) return 'ie';
  else if (sBrowser.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) return 'firefox';
  else return 'mozilla';
}
```

You just need to check the possible browser names than return the name of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by css condition

```
body{background-color:#0FF; } /* for normal browser */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { body{background-color:#F90;} } /* for webkit browser like crome, safari */

@-moz-document url-prefix() { body{ background-color:#090;}} /* for firefox */
```

but this is not a valid css